# Persistent Current in Superconductors

Tags: electric-current, superconductivity

Persistent current is the current which flows forever in a superconductor.

In picture we have two conductors. In figure "A" we have a round superconductor and when we give voltage to it and then disconnect the voltage, current will flow round and round forever and it makes sense.

But in figure "B" we have a straight conductor and when we give voltage to it and then disconnect the voltage, current is also supposed to flow forever.

But my confusion is that how the current will flow in that straight conductor as it is an open terminal on both terminals so how the current will flow in it ? Ofcourse none of the terminals of the straight conductor have the path for the current to flow. So how current will behave in that open ended straight conductor.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "open terminals"? Is the straight conductor finite or infinite? If finite, are its ends attached to any other conductors/superconductors?

Comment: Re, "my confusion is that how the current will flow in [an open circuit.]" Where did you get the idea that current _could_ flow in an open circuit? I'm not an expert, but I _imagine_ that current could bounce back and forth in a straight segment in the same way that it does in a [dipole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna). But in fact, the segment actually would _be_ a dipole antenna in that case, and it would quickly radiate all of the energy away.

Comment: @alexey. No ends are not attached to any conductor?

Comment: @Solomon Slow will it radiate all of the energy away even its a super conductor with zero resistance? And if it radiates energy, will current be zero then?

Comment: @Alex, Yes. I'm afraid that I can't explain how an antenna works, but I know that it has nothing to do with resistance, and it has much to do with moving charges (i.e., moving electrons.)

Comment: I think some of the confusion also stems from the phrase "give voltage to a system". Voltage is not a unit of energy or momentum or something like that. In circuits, we can meaningfully talk about _potential differences_ between two points, also known as _voltage drops_. But we cannot "give voltage". So for the (in?)finite straight wire, the question becomes how do we apply a voltage difference between two points along the wire. For ordinary circuits, we can do this by _closing the circuit_ with a battery.